# Python - extract <iframe> source

Tags: python, iframe

I have a nested list of `<iframes>`:

```
iframes = [
[<iframe data-lazy-src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/309819830&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false" frameborder="no" height="166" scrolling="no" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" width="100%"></iframe>, <iframe allowtransparency="true" data-lazy-src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPauseMusicale&amp;width=300&amp;height=62&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false&amp;header=false" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:62px;"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" data-lazy-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLNKCTdT9YSESoQnj5tPP4P9kaIwBCx7F1" frameborder="0" height="169" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" width="100%"></iframe>], [<iframe data-lazy-src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/310079005&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false" frameborder="no" height="166" scrolling="no" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" width="100%"></iframe>, <iframe allowtransparency="true" data-lazy-src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPauseMusicale&amp;width=300&amp;height=62&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false&amp;header=false" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:62px;"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" data-lazy-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLNKCTdT9YSESoQnj5tPP4P9kaIwBCx7F1" frameborder="0" height="169" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" width="100%"></iframe>],
[<iframe etc], 
[<iframe etc]]
```

and I want to fetch all `['data-lazy-src']` from it.

I'm using this code for this purpose:

```
for iframe in iframes:
    for i in iframe:        
        scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(i.attrs['data-lazy-src'])
        if not scheme:
            scheme = 'http'   
        url = urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment))
        print('Fetching {}'.format(url))
        f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

but I'm getting:

```
Fetching http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLNKCTdT9YSESoQnj5tPP4P9kaIwBCx7F1
Fetching http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLNKCTdT9YSESoQnj5tPP4P9kaIwBCx7F1
Fetching http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLNKCTdT9YSESoQnj5tPP4P9kaIwBCx7F1
```

I know I'm missing something terribly obvious, but I just can't see it.

Comment: `iframes` is a list of list of string?

Comment: yes. nested list.

Comment: Without `'` and `'`?

Comment: yes. when I print the list, thats how it prints. is it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can get html strings from your `iframes` then pass it into BeautifulSoup  to parse it easily. Try something like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

iframe = '<iframe data-lazy-src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/309819830..." frameborder="no"></iframe>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(iframe, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find_all('iframe')[0]
print(tag['data-lazy-src'])
```

Comment: that won't do it. the code used in the question is required, because some urls in the nested list have strange schema, such as `//www` without `http`, and that must be correct as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the way the nested list was generated, appending `soup.find_all('iframe')` to `iframes = []`.

once the appending part was removed, it worked as follows:

```
   (...)

    iframes = soup.find_all('iframe')  

for iframe in iframes:
    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(iframe.attrs['data-lazy-src'])
    if not scheme:
        scheme = 'http' # default scheme you used when getting the current page
    url = urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment))
    print('Fetching {}'.format(url))
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

results:

```
Fetching https://www.youtube.com/embed/OWr5FawT2Ks?rel=0
Fetching https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/308112514&color=ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false
Fetching http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPauseMusicale&width=300&height=62&show_faces=false&colorscheme=light&stream=false&show_border=false&header=false
Fetching http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLNKCTdT9YSESoQnj5tPP4P9kaIwBCx7F1
```